# Rails Query to Group Content

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model as follows

```
missions(id, mission_details, city, state)
```

I want to create a data Table that will list all the Cities/States and the Missions under it.

If a Particular City/State has more than one mission. Then i want to concatenate it and display it together.

Which is the best way to query the same.

Comment: Mission.group("city, state") is the query I need.. I don't understand the _concat_ patrt..

Answer (score 1):

You should do :

```
Mission.group("city, state")
       .select("city,state,GROUP_CONCAT(mission_details, SEPARATOR '|')")
```

Read this: [GROUP_CONCAT(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)